# IAB HTML5 CSS3 banners delivery specs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing some animated banners mainly using jQuery and such. The cliënt wants to distribute the banners according IAB standards to their resellers (hundreds). The problem is, that I can simply not find what standard delivery specs are. I don't think the code and files will Be included in a reseller site, because e.g. JQuery versions might conflict. I also doubt an iFrame should be used.

In other words, I have no clue and Google returns no solid answer.

Does anyone know how This normally should work, how To setup the files and how To embed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

IAB is like an umbrella standard and two main Studio to publish Rich Media html banners are google's DoubleClick and Sizmek. You should develop your banners with one of their specs and then you can publish it to any website you want. The following link will give you the specification for sizmek:

https://support.sizmek.com/hc/en-us/articles/202732315-HTML5-Formats-and-Features

And the following is for Doubleclick:

https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2672545?hl=en&ref_topic=2672541&vid=1-635803329575855222-3463806884

In your question you wrote that you used jQuery and you don't know if the website version allows it or not.

From my experience, you cannot rely on the website javascript library and you should always package your javascript, CSSs and images you used on the banners in the same folder with the .html file. Keep in mind you have total file size limitation and usually publishers does not allow you to use minified version of external library. Long story short, it is not advisable to use jQuery for html banners & it is better to use other lightweight libraries that does not effect mobile browsers performance ([zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com) is a good alternative).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. The problem is the implementation and distribution is really up to you. Once you create a rich media ad package using the `[IAB rising star standards.][1]` you'll need to figure out what distribution system  you will use.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you perhaps tell me what common distribution methods are? Google (itself) advices Gzip, some sites do iframes and others use javascript ad-tags. If iframes are accepted on a "normal" base, I guess I am going for that.

Comment: An Ad Broker service, Google, I think you will need to do a bit more research to define your problem some more. There are several ad networks out there that distribute advertisements as a publisher.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your ad network's specs, but JQuery is usually not feasible for ad banners, where the standard file size limit is 40kb.  You won't have much room left for an image if you include JQuery. The most efficient way to do animated html banners is with css transitions and minimal javascript. If you must use javascript, you'll have better luck with a smaller package like GSAP or Zepto.